# Regex to get the text between two characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, replace

I want to replace a text after a forward slash and before a end parantheses excluding the characters.

```
My text: 
<h3>notThisText/IWantToReplaceThis)<h3>

$('h3').text($('h3').text().replace(regEx, 'textReplaced'));

Wanted result after replace:
notThisText/textReplaced)
```

I have tried

```
regex = /([^\/]+$)+/ //replaces the parantheses as well 
regex = \/([^\)]+) //replaces the slash as well
```

but as you can see in my comments neither of these excludes both the slash and the end parantheses. Can someone help?

Comment: You may add the `/` in the replacement pattern, `.replace(/\/[^)]*\)/, '/textReplaced)')`.

Comment: Yes, but that is not what I am looking for

Comment: So you are saying it's not possible to write a regEx matching a text between two characters exluding the characters in JS?

Comment: I want to say you do not have to do it. You should know that a pattern like `/(?<=\/)[^)]+(?=\))/` won't work in JS as its regex engine does not support look*behind*. So, you should either use what I suggest, or a similar `replace(/(\/)[^)]+(\))/, '$1textReplaced$2')`

Comment: Aha I see, thanks. I'll go for your suggestion then :)

Comment: I posted an answer showing various ways to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pattern like `/(?<=\/)[^)]+(?=\))/` won't work in JS as its regex engine does not support a lookbehind construct. So, you should use one of the following solutions:

```
s.replace(/(\/)[^)]+(\))/, '$1textReplaced$2')
s.replace(/(\/)[^)]+(?=\))/, '$1textReplaced')
s.replace(/(\/)[^)]+/, '$1textReplaced')
s.replace(/\/[^)]+\)/, '/textReplaced)')
```

The `(...)` forms a capturing group that can be referenced to with `$` + number, a backreference, from the replacement pattern. The first solution is consuming `/` and `)`, and puts them into capturing groups. If you need to match consecutive, overlapping matches, use the second solution (`s.replace(/(\/)[^)]+(?=\))/, '$1textReplaced')`). If the `)` is not required at the end, the third solution (`replace(/(\/)[^)]+/, '$1textReplaced')`) will do. The last solution (`s.replace(/\/[^)]+\)/, '/textReplaced)')`) will work if the `/` and `)` are static values known beforehand.

Comment: Wow thanks, I ended up using the second solution, works great!

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "notThisText/IWantToReplaceThis";
text = text.replace(/\/.*/, "/whatever");
output : "notThisText/whatever"`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.split('/')`

```
var text = 'notThisText/IWantToReplaceThis';
var splited = text.split('/');
splited[1] = 'yourDesireText';
var output = splited.join('/');
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following: In your case startChar='/', endChar = ')', origString=$('h3').text()

```
function customReplace(startChar, endChar, origString, replaceWith){
var strArray = origString.split(startChar);
return strArray[0] + startChar + replaceWith + endChar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you didn't define clearly what is the format of the text which you want to replace and the non-replacement part. For example,

- Does `notThisText` contain any slash `/`?
- Does `IWantToReplaceThis` contain any parentheses `)`?

Since there are too many uncertainties, the answer here only shows up the pattern exactly matches your example:

```
yourText.replace(/(\/).*?(\))/g, '$1textReplaced$2')
```